# To match a list type column with other columns in DF

Tags: r, regex, match

I have a data frame with the approximate structure:

```
         C1                   C2      C3
1  c("XXX", "Y3")            "XXX"   "Y31"
2  c("SFM", "DD31", "DSDW")  "SFF"   "DD31"
```

The column C1 is a list. It was a string which I split into separate words. The other 2 columns are character.
I need to match C2 and C3 against C1 so that in case of the match (100% there is a match), replace the value in C1 with another value. For example:

The first row has 2 matches because fuzzy match is also a match:

1. C1~C2: replace "XXX" in C1 with the modified value from C1 "XXX[TAG]"
2. C1~C3: replace "Y3"  in C1 with the modified value from C3 "Y31[TAG]"

In general I understand how to do that: with a for loop, match function and regex but my knowledge does not allow me to combine everything together. Thank you in advance!

### **EDITED**

**What I have:**

```
x <- structure(list(Description = list(c("2012", "Deere", "544K", 
                                    "Wheel", "Loader,"), c("Caterpillar","Model", "988", "Year", "1972")), 
                    Manufacturer = c("john deere", "caterpillar"), 
                    Model = c("544k", "988")), .Names = c("Description", "Manufacturer", "Model"), row.names = 4:5, class = "data.frame")


#>     Description                        Manufacturer Model
#> 4   2012, Deere, 544K, Wheel, Loader,   john deere  544k
#> 5 Caterpillar, Model, 988, Year, 1972  caterpillar   988
```

**What I want to have:**

```
x.new <- structure(list(Description = list(c("2012", "john deere[Manufacturer]", "544k[Model]", 
                                         "Wheel", "Loader,"), c("caterpillar[Manufacturer]","Model", "988[Model]", "Year", "1972")), 
                    Manufacturer = c("john deere", "caterpillar"), 
                    Model = c("544k", "988")), .Names = c("Description", "Manufacturer", "Model"), row.names = 4:5, class = "data.frame")

#>  Description                                                 Manufacturer Model
#> 4 2012, john deere[Manufacturer], 544k[Model], Wheel, Loader,  john deere  544k
#> 5 caterpillar[Manufacturer], Model, 988[Model], Year, 1972    caterpillar   988
```

Comment: I think there is a typo. Do you mean 2.C1~C3: replace "Y3" in C1 with the modified value from C3 "Y31"   (first one is Y3 not Y31)

Comment: You are right! + I found another typo. Thanks!

Comment: Please read: [How to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With list columns, you'll need a lot of `lapply` and its multivariate equivalent, `Map`, which allow you to iterate over the list column and return a list which can be reassigned as a column. For example,

```r
df <- structure(list(C1 = list(c("XXX", "Y3"), c("SFM", "DD31", "DSDW")), 
                     C2 = c("XXX", "SFF"), 
                     C3 = c("Y31", "DD31")), 
                .Names = c("C1", "C2", "C3"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

df$C1_new <- Map(function(c1, c2, c3){
    sapply(c1, function(x){
        mtch <- grepl(x, c(c2, c3)); 
        if (any(mtch)) {paste0(c(c2, c3)[mtch], '[', names(df)[-1][mtch], ']')} else {x}
    })},
    df$C1, df$C2, df$C3)

df
#>                C1  C2   C3              C1_new
#> 1         XXX, Y3 XXX  Y31    XXX[C2], Y31[C3]
#> 2 SFM, DD31, DSDW SFF DD31 SFM, DD31[C3], DSDW
```

There are many other ways to set this up, including using using packages like `purrr` and `stringr` that make the syntax simpler and more uniform. Vary as you like.

To apply to the second dataset listed, it works with some slight edits:

```r
x <- structure(list(Description = list(c("2012", "Deere", "544K", "Wheel", "Loader,"), 
                                       c("Caterpillar","Model", "988", "Year", "1972")), 
                    Manufacturer = c("john deere", "caterpillar"), 
                    Model = c("544k", "988")), 
               .Names = c("Description", "Manufacturer", "Model"), row.names = 4:5, class = "data.frame")

x$Description <- Map(function(desc, mfr, mdl){
    sapply(desc, function(wrd){
        mtch <- grepl(wrd, c(mfr, mdl), ignore.case = TRUE); 
        if (any(mtch)) {paste0(c(mfr, mdl)[mtch], '[', names(x)[-1][mtch], ']')} else {wrd}
    })},
    x$Description, x$Manufacturer, x$Model)

x
#>                                                   Description Manufacturer Model
#> 4 2012, john deere[Manufacturer], 544k[Model], Wheel, Loader,   john deere  544k
#> 5    caterpillar[Manufacturer], Model, 988[Model], Year, 1972  caterpillar   988
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly ;)